# How to store a multidimensional array in an Ecto schema?

Tags: elixir, ecto

Say I wish to store a set of coordinates (`[[x1,y1], [x2,y2]]`) into Postgres. What is the preferable datatype? The docs allow for arrays in the form of

```
:coordinates, {:array, :float}
```

But this is only useful for one-dimensional arrays.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use

```
field :coordinates, {:array, {:array, :float}}
```

but it isn't best solution. Looks bad and allows something like this `[[1.0]]` to be inserted to database, which is clearly not coordinate. I would prefer custom type.

```
#lib/coordinates.ex
defmodule Coordinates do
  @behaviour Ecto.Type

  def type, do: {:array, :float}

  def cast([l1, l2] = coordinates) when is_list(l1) and length(l1) == 2 and is_list(l2) and length(l2) == 2 do
    flattened_list = coordinates |> List.flatten

    cond do
      Enum.all?(flattened_list, &(is_float(&1))) ->
        {:ok, list}
      # add additional [integer, string, ...] to float transformations here if necessary
      # Enum.all?(flattened_list, &(is_float(&1) || is_integer(&1))) ->
      #   normalized = flattened_list |> Enum.map(&(&1 / 1)) |> Enum.split(2) |> Tuple.to_list
      #
      #   {:ok, normalized}
      true ->
        :error
    end
  end

  def cast(_), do: :error

  def load(list) when is_list(list) and length(list) == 4 do
    two_dimensional_list = list |> Enum.split(2) |> Tuple.to_list

    {:ok, two_dimensional_list}
  end

  def dump(list) when is_list(list) and length(list) == 2 do
    flattened_list = coordinates |> List.flatten

    {:ok, flattened_list}
  end

  def dump(_), do: :error
end

#web/models/your_model.ex
schema "your_model" do
  field :coordinates, Coordinates
end
```

According to docs Ecto.Type behaviour expects 4 functions to be implemented.

> type should output the name of the DB type
>   cast should receive any type and output your custom Ecto type
>   load should receive the DB type and output your custom Ecto type
>   dump should receive your custom Ecto type and output the DB type

Most important in example above are dump and load (transformations between one and two dimensional lists) and a lot of guards (ensure that invalid data will return :error)

I recommend to read full `Ecto.Type` docs:
https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Type.html 
It's very helpful.

Comment: Thanks. Ended up using `field :coordinates, {:array, {:array, :float}}` with migration type `{:array, :float}` for simplicity. (List can be variable length, so custom type code would be more complex... and there's a tight deadline haha.